# function to convers from hex to binary with all byte

Tags: java, function, binary, hex

I've tried a few solutions but all of them reduce the solution to only 6 bytes

for example if I send "3C" to this function it will show ----> 111100

I need it to be -----> 00111100

```
public static String hexToBinary(String hex) {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
            
        String bin = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
        
        return bin;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I'm afraid `Integer.toBinaryString` is broken and printf doesn't help. You could do this:

```
public static String hexToBinary(String hex) {
    int i = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
    String bin = "00000000" + Integer.toBinaryString(i);
    return bin.substring(bin.length() - 8);
}
```

Though I wrote my own versions of these converters early on in the life of Java